# Unable to load class com.android.build.gradle.managed.NdkConfig$Impl

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

I just upgraded to AS 2.0 Preview 8 and I'm trying to build my old project.  I updated it to be

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha8'
```

and updated the `gradle-wrapper.properties` to use `gradle-2.10-all.zip`, but when I try to build my project I get a Java stactrace saying:

```
Unable to load class com.android.build.gradle.managed.NdkConfig$Impl
```

I'm using Java 8 to start AS as well as having that set as the JDK for the project.  I was also having the same problem with Java7.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, this was fixed by simply doing a Gradle `clean`.  Hope this helps someone else as this was not intuitive

Comment: Didn't help me unfortunately

Answer (score 10):

The problem with my project was due to a change in the `gradle-experimental` plugin:

> += no longer works for collections.  Adding items to the list can be done with the 'add' or 'addAll' method.  e.g. CFlags +=
>   "-DCUSTOM_DEFINE" can be replaced with CFlags.add("-DCUSTOM_DEFINE")

Changed those occurrences and the build finished successfully.